# Interface Builder - Using Layout View-Box

Tags: cocoa, macos, xcode4, interface-builder

I'm using a Layout View - 'Box' in my application and when i build it, I'm getting the following warning.
"Unsupported Configuration. Fill Color property requires NSCustomBox type and NSLineBorder type".I'm using XCode 4.0.
What could be the reason and how can i fix it?

Thanks,

LS Developer

Comment: Have you tried using `NSCustomBox` and `NSLineBorder`?

Answer (score 4):

If I set border color or fill color of a non-custom primary box to anything other than the color IB initializes it as, I get a warning "Border Color Property requires NSCustomBox type and NSLineBorder type"

I can make the warning go away by dragging the 'initial' color from a box in a DIFFERENT project onto the offending color choice in the box's Attribute IB inspector pane.

Fill color changes produce slightly different warning text, but dragging the fill color from a pristine box in another project eliminates that warning as well.
Apple seems to have forgotten to put an 'initial value' item in their color choice menus.

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never, but as I was searching, this was the only thread I found describing the matter. Anyway, thanks Wayfaring Stranger, your answer helped me find an alternative fix. Might help someone, since the drag and drop of colors didn't exactly work for me.

1. Find your box in interface builder and give it a unique name (just temporarily).
2. Right click your .xib and choose 'open as' > 'source code'.
3. Do a search for the name you've given your box (or whatever).
4. You'll find something like this:

   ```
   <object class="NSTextFieldCell" key="NSTitleCell">
       <int key="NSCellFlags">67108864</int>
       <int key="NSCellFlags2">0</int>
       <string key="NSContents">uniqueNameHere</string>
       <reference key="NSSupport" ref="26"/>
       <reference key="NSBackgroundColor" ref="449986353"/>
       <object class="NSColor" key="NSTextColor">
           <int key="NSColorSpace">3</int>
           <bytes key="NSWhite">MCAwLjgwMDAwMDAxMTkAA</bytes>
       </object>
   </object>
   <reference key="NSContentView" ref="183372649"/>
   <int key="NSBorderType">0</int>
   <int key="NSBoxType">0</int>
   <int key="NSTitlePosition">0</int>
   <bool key="NSTransparent">NO</bool>
   <bool key="NSFullyTransparent">YES</bool>
   <real value="0.0" key="NSBorderWidth2"/>
   <object class="NSColor" key="NSBorderColor2" id="483112007">
       <int key="NSColorSpace">6</int>
       <string key="NSCatalogName">System</string>
       <string key="NSColorName">textColor</string>
       <reference key="NSColor" ref="703464901"/>
   </object>
   <reference key="NSFillColor2" ref="483112007"/>
   ```
5. Remove everything after `<bool key="NSTransparent">NO</bool>` up to the next `</object></array>`, leaving you with:

   ```
   <object class="NSTextFieldCell" key="NSTitleCell">
       <int key="NSCellFlags">67108864</int>
       <int key="NSCellFlags2">0</int>
       <string key="NSContents">uniqueNameHere</string>
       <reference key="NSSupport" ref="26"/>
       <reference key="NSBackgroundColor" ref="449986353"/>
       <object class="NSColor" key="NSTextColor">
           <int key="NSColorSpace">3</int>
           <bytes key="NSWhite">MCAwLjgwMDAwMDAxMTkAA</bytes>
       </object>
   </object>
   <reference key="NSContentView" ref="183372649"/>
   <int key="NSBorderType">0</int>
   <int key="NSBoxType">0</int>
   <int key="NSTitlePosition">0</int>
   <bool key="NSTransparent">NO</bool>
   ```
6. All your warnings for that item will disappear except for one: `This archive contains a reference to an object with the identifier "483112007" but does not contain an object with a matching identifier.` Search for that number in your .xib source code and remove that line, e.g. `<reference key="NSBorderColor2" ref="483112007"/>`. In my case, it was just a few lines further down.

Still haven't figured out the cause of the problem though. Never had any warnings setting colors, and this one unexpectedly popped up after accidentally dragging some items in IB.

Answer (score 2):

I solved dragging and dropping the colors from an NSBox in a new project as Wayfaring Stranger suggested. If you want to change manually the XIB, the changes (I'm on Xcode 5.0.2) are:

Deleted (your values will be probably different, that's the "default color":

```
- <color key="borderColor" name="textColor" catalog="System" colorSpace="catalog"/>
- <color key="fillColor" name="textColor" catalog="System" colorSpace="catalog"/>
```

Substituted with:

```
+ <color key="borderColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.41999999999999998" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
+ <color key="fillColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
```

of course, in the relevant  section. XIBs are version 5.

Comment: Xcode 6.2 here, I got rid of the warning by copying the `borderColor` and `fillColor` tags from a freshly instantiated NSBox. In addition, I had to clean the project, close Xcode, and rebuild to finally get the warnings to disappear

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jonas' answer, I managed to fix my warnings by searching for NSTransparent in the .xib file:

Right click or ctrl-click your .xib and choose 'Open As -> Source Code'

Search for NSTransparent to find something similar to:

```
<bool key="NSTransparent">NO</bool>
<object class="NSColor" key="NSFillColor2">
  <int key="NSColorSpace">1</int>
 <bytes key="NSRGB">MSAwLjgwMDAwMDAxMTkgMC40MDAwMDAwMDYgMC4wNAA</bytes>
</object>
```

I then deleted `<object class="NSColor"` to `</object>` inclusive and the warnings were no more.

Answer (score 0):

I simply solved the issue by choosing Custom from Box Type in IB. That made the message go away immediately.

First I was puzzled by the message since I did a similar thing (namely changing the background color of a NSBox) to white in another project. But then I remembered that I also changed the Box Type. And that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As my box was merely cosmetic, I created a new box, moved the buttons in the old box to the new box, and deleted the old box. End of problem.